# Access to All Files which is Selected from a MultiSelected openfileDialog in C++

Tags: c++, winforms, filenames, openfiledialog

I am writing a project in windows form application in Visual Studio C++ 2010;

I have an openfileDialog which its MultiSelected Property is true;

I need to access to all the file's name; but every time which I run the program even I select the several files, I just see the first file which is selected in brows window.

my code is here:

```
 if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
                 {
                     FileCounter  = 0;

                     for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->FileNames)
                     {

                         String ^orig1 = gcnew String(openFileDialog1->FileNames[FileCounter]);
```

How Can I do that? 
Thank you So much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is not complete, try out something like

```
for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->FileNames)
{
    MessageBox::Show(file);
}
```

Comment: I want to save the file names in a XML File; you mean I can Access to each name through "file" ?

Comment: yes, `openFileDialog1->FileNames` is a string array -- see [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I'm glad it helped; just a note: it is customary in SO to upvote and/or "accept as answer" when the answer was useful and/or answered your question, this will also be useful to other people who come across your question...